# Shell script command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, shell, unicorn

I am working on a unicorn shell script that is suposed to start/stop/restart unicorn. How ever I am having a bit of trouble getting it to actually work.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

When I run the shell script (sh unicorn_init.sh) I get the following output.

```
    kill: 72: No such process

    unicorn_init.sh: 72: cd /data/appname/staging/releases/20120823055753; bundle exec unicorn_rails -D -c /data/appname/staging/releases/20120823055753/config/unicorn.rb -E staging: not found
```

This is the current version of my shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Example init script, this can be used with nginx, too,
# since nginx and unicorn accept the same signals

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/data/appname/staging/releases/20120823055753
SHARED_ROOT=/data/appname/staging/shared
PID=$SHARED_ROOT/pids/unicorn-staging.pid
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn_rails -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E staging"
action="$1"
set -u

old_pid="$PID.oldbin"

cd $APP_ROOT || exit 1

sig () {
        test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
        test -s $old_pid && kill -$1 `cat $old_pid`
}

case $action in
start)
        sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
        "$CMD"
        ;;
stop)
        sig QUIT && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Not running"
        ;;
force-stop)
        sig TERM && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Not running"
        ;;
restart|reload)
        sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
        "$CMD"
        ;;
upgrade)
        if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
        then
                n=$TIMEOUT
                while test -s $old_pid && test $n -ge 0
                do
                        printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
                done
                echo

                if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $old_pid
                then
                        echo >&2 "$old_pid still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
                        exit 1
                fi
                exit 0
        fi
        echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
        "$CMD"
        ;;
reopen-logs)
        sig USR1
        ;;
*)
        echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: By quick glance, you need to modify `sig` to (1) not display error output from `kill` if the process doesn't exist, and (2) not die.  Because of the `set -e` your script will terminate if you try to terminate a process which is no longer running.  It's not hard to fix, but coding for `set -e` is a bit more challenging.

Comment: Remove the quotes from around `"$CMD"`

Answer (score 2):

The quotes around `$CMD` mean that the entire variable value is  a command, including embedded spaces.  Here is a simple example to illustrate:

```
/home/user1> CMD='echo hello'
/home/user1> $CMD
hello
/home/user1> "$CMD"
-bash: echo hello: command not found
/home/user1>
```